# webpack convert css unit with uglifyjs plugin

Tags: webpack, uglifyjs

It's weird, actually, I think it is quite easy to come across, but I have found nothing about this issue~

I have tested with / without uglifyjs plugin, and I'm quite sure that this plugin results in this issue.

In my style files, only px / em have been used, but after compression, some of px has been converted to pc / pt, totally have no clue~

[image]

Comment: I found it too, have you resolved it?

Comment: nope, it's weird, but working fine.

Comment: I upgrade my css-loader and have it resolved

Comment: Hey, if my answer solves the problem, please mark it as such: ) best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though UglifyJS has **JS** in name it affects other loaders.
The answer is somewhat hidden in the [UglifyJSPlugin docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#uglifyjsplugin).

> Minimize all JavaScript output of chunks. **Loaders are switched into
>   minimizing mode.** (...)

The discussion about it takes place here:

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/283

No workaround yet as I see.

I would say as long as it doesn't mess your build, keep using uglifyJS. When it starts, you can try

1. Switching to Babili (babel based minifier) + babili-webpack-plugin.

   https://babeljs.io/blog/2016/08/30/babili

   https://www.npmjs.com/package/babili-webpack-plugin

   and minifying your CSS with css-loader minimize option.

> From https://github.com/webpack/css-loader :
>
> You can also disable or enforce minification with the minimize query
>
> ```
> parameter.
>
> require("css-loader?minimize!./file.css") (enforced)
> require("css-loader?-minimize!./file.css") (disabled)
> ```

or

2. Disabling minimize option in css-loader plugin (overwriting uglifyJS behavior). Don't worry your CSSes **will** be minimized, just bit less (in my case). - better this than crashing production build.

I tried Babili without success but second option helped in production build of my project.

Comment: Babili minifier worked for me! UglifyJS still messed with my css files by formatting them even with the minimize options disabled. Thank you!

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson glad I could help: )